# pandas conditional str concat with a Datetime column

Tags: python, string, pandas, concatenation, string-concatenation

I would like to join only the day-ahead with the year of my Date column to make it look like day-ahead_2019 or day-ahead_2018 depending on the year in Date column

I have two columns:

```
DELIVERY_PERIOD   
day-ahead
day-ahead
day-ahead
day-ahead
week1_2019
week2_2018
```

and,

```
Date
13/05/2019
14/05/2019
11/05/2019
10/05/2019
```

I tried to use str.cat but it doesnt work for datetime64 for my Date column

```
       df.DELIVERY_PERIOD == 'day-ahead' = df.str.cat(df.Date.dt.year)
```

error came up as it is not str type data
i thought about the other way around
which is create new columns to get year from the Date.dt.year, convert it to str and only join with day-ahead
but i think this would be a long way around
i welcome any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this,

assuming your dataframe is called df

you can pass the `astype` function to transform your series into a string and pass this back to your new or existing series.

```
df['DELIVERY_PERIOD'] = df.loc[df['DELIVERY_PERIOD'] == 'day-ahead', 'DELIVERY_PERIOD'] = df['DELIVERY_PERIOD'] + '_' + df['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
print(df)


 DELIVERY_PERIOD    Date
0   day-ahead_2019  2019-05-13
1   day-ahead_2019  2019-05-14
2   day-ahead_2019  2019-11-05
3   day-ahead_2019  2019-11-05
```

Comment: another question on this, say if i have more than just day-ahead i want to join the year, i tried to make a filter list with day-ahead and week-ahead. i.e filterlist = filterlist = gas[gas['Period'].isin(['day-ahead',' 'week-ahead])] and follow with this :                              gas.loc[gas['Period'] == filterlist,'Period'] = gas['Period'] + '_' + gas['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)     i ended up with this error: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Thanks, if this was the answer you should green tick :) it's hard to say, can you create a new question with an input and output sample we can help thay way

Comment: no problem, will get a new question up soon. THANK YOU